# After animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I need to develop an animation android like this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwJN1Wzmr1o
at the transition between views 
you can give me an example please.

thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should learn more about android animations first or check out some tutorials before asking here? This for example: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html

Comment: Thank you, i want use an animation same in this vidéo, in the tutoriel we have a classic animation, it's possible to make this with android? I'm sorry for my English writing :(

Answer (score 0):

To transition between activities you would need to call:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.righttocenter, R.anim.centertoleft);
```

And replace `righttocenter` and `centertoleft` with your own animation file names, in a `anim` folder under `res`. You will have to look in to creating the animations yourself using XML.

Comment: Thank you, i want use an animation same in this vidéo, in the tutoriel we have a classic animation, it's possible to make this with android? I'm sorry for my English writing :(